# Salesforce Community : Tabs not dipslayed

Tags: community, tab, customer-community, libraries

I am working on Salesforce community. I created a new site using Nappli template and did some customization with site.com and using branding. On the "community management", under Administration > Tabs, I have added Libraries and Q&A. But they are not displayed on the top navigation bar of the site. How do I display it? I do have permissions to view the libraries and Q&A. I checked my profile and I do see the permission. Also, I don't see option to add libraries as page element in site.com too.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Anyone got idea?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the template "Nappli" to "Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce template" to view the tabs.